# Meteor 0.6.5 update breaks router function

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I recently updated my meteor app to 0.6.5 and I noticed that the router package is not working properly, so I also did a mrt update, but there are still issues. For example, accessing routes does not render the appropriate template. When I run the router test there is also this issue:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
```

I noticed that there was an update to meteor router, but my app is failing to render the corresponding route-template.

Please let me know if there is a method to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor router doesn't yet support 0.6.5. It should do shortly as it just has to be slightly modified to work with the new version of meteor containing the linker branch. Why not consider the move to [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-iron-router).

[Tom Coleman](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) (author of meteor-router) & [Chris Mather](http://eventedmind.com) worked to build it. It is compatible with 0.6.5

Answer (score 4):

Meteor Router has been updated to support 0.6.5. Note also that there will be the last (non bugfix) release and there is a new router project called [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-iron-router) that will replace Meteor Router.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, and more generally for mrt packages, you may need to downgrade to 0.6.4.1 until the package author has had a chance to update to the new package API that is part of 0.6.5. You can find instructions here - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-talk/BbrjGcGGIzc/discussion